# Do 3rd party JDK builds offer javadocs?

Tags: java, javadoc, java-11

When I install a new JDK, I follow similar procedures as described [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html).

For example, like that link, I too like to have a local copy of the javadocs.  See that link's "Step 7: (Optional) Download JDK API Documentation, Demos and Samples" section.

My only use for these javadocs is to point my IDE (IntelliJ, of course!) at them.  I will not be doing anything commercial with them, like redistributing them, developing my own JDK, etc.

In the past, I always downloaded Sun/Oracle's JDK, and a javadoc .zip file was also downloadable from the same web page as the JDK.

Starting with JDK 11, there are now many new 3rd party builds to chose [from](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/01/16/which-java-sdk).

I have no strong preference among them.  I have selected Azul's Zulu for now simply because I respect their technology in general.

My problem is that every 3rd party JDK 11 build that I looked at, including Azul Zulu, seems to only offer you just the JDK.  None of them seem to have a javadoc download (e.g. a jdk-11.0.3_doc-all.zip file).

**Did I overlook where to get this?**

*Or is Oracle still the only source for this?  And is Oracle's license for these javadocs a problem?*

Of course I did a web search before posting this question, as well as I manually searched thru all the 3rd party build web pages.  The only source that I found for downloadable javadocs was Oracle.

So, I downloaded my current copy of jdk-11.0.3_doc-all.zip from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
by clicking on this [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk11-doc-downloads-5097203.html), then accepting the [license agreement](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/java_se-11-final-spec/license.html), then clicking on the jdk-11.0.3_doc-all.zip link, then logging in to Oracle.

I am concerned about getting this documentation from Oracle because I assume that the license that I agreed to is no longer a free one as in the past.

If I only use Oracle's javadocs locally, by pointing my IDE towards them, will that violate Oracle's license?  I will be using my IDE to develop commercial software.

Yes, I have skimmed thru that [license](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/java_se-11-final-spec/license.html).  But it is legalese, and I do not really understand it.  It has concerning language like "Specification Lead hereby grants you a...license...to view, download, use and reproduce the Specification **only for the purpose of internal evaluation**".

Comment: Seems you are asking for off site resources, thus rendering your question off topic. Still an important question.

Comment: This could also be construed as a request for legal advice ... about whether there is actually anything concerning about the Oracle documentation license for what you are going to do with the documentation.

Comment: There have always been 3rd party JDK offerings (eg by IBM, Azul and others). That is not something that is new, it is just more visible now that Oracle decided to change the licensing of their JDK.

Comment: most linux distro packages contain javadocs

Answer (score 2):

> Or is Oracle still the only source for this?

I am not aware of any such 3rd-party download<sup>1</sup>

> And is Oracle's license for these javadocs a problem?

That would be for you to decide *after reading the license*<sup>2</sup>.  Among other things, it would depend on how you intend to use the documentation.

> Yes, I have skimmed thru that license. But it is legalese, and I do not really understand it.  Eetcetera

See footnote 2.  Seriously.  **We can't answer your legal questions with any confidence.**  And even if we did, you *should* have no confidence in our answers!

---

One alternative is to download the OpenJDK source tree and build the javadocs for yourself.  Your usage of the resulting javadocs will be (only) limited<sup>2</sup> by the terms of the GPL v2 + Classpath license for OpenJDK.

A second alternative is to view the Oracle javadocs via the web.

A third alternative is to point your preferred IDE at the appropriate source code bundle (in your Oracle JDK or OpenJDK installation) and search / view the docs via your IDE.

---

<sup>1 - If such a download does exist, you *should* be able to find it with a Google search.</sup>

<sup>2 - I am not a lawyer!  If you are concerned about this, you should get legal advice from a practicing lawyer.</sup>